# protobuf-net on TCP stream?

Tags: serialization, tcp, deserialization

Okay just got TCP to work, and noticed that a binary formatter is used to make it "network friendly" i think.

Anyway, so the code is like this:

Client

```
Serializer.Serialize(tcpcap.GetStream(), u);
```

Server

```
byte[] u = Serializer.Deserialize<byte[]>(tt1.GetStream());
```

u is Not the same on both of them, i just have the same name, but u is a byte array on both parts.

And well, it doesn´t work.

It does work with:

```
(byte[])b.Deserialize(tt1.GetStream());
 b.Serialize(tcpcap.GetStream(), u);
```

where b is new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

There is probably an obvious reason why it isn´t working, but i don´t really know what Serialization is, so for me, it´s not that obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, or well not using protobuf, but NetSerialization, got help from the Author.

So let´s say this is answered.